# "Argument of \pgfkeys@@normal has an extra }" error when using TikZ's fit library

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error, fit

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
%   \node[draw, fit=(0,0) (1,1)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: A square]

If the two commented lines are now uncommented, and the command `pdflatex test` is rerun, the execution fails, and the file `~/test.log` contains the following snippet:

```
! Argument of \pgfkeys@@normal has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9    \node[draw, fit=(0,0) (1,1)]
                                    {};
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9    \node[draw, fit=(0,0) (1,1)]
                                    {};
End of file on the terminal!
```

Why does the execution fail? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: the commas split up keys so you have `draw, fit=(0,`  so misformed value, but I do not know what you intended, I see no similar syntax in the tikz manual fitting section

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's peculiar that you saw no similar syntax in the *TikZ & PGF Manual*'s *Fitting* section, since one of the first paragraphs of this section (on p. 685 of the current version, 3.1.9a, of this manual) reads: "/tikz/fit=<coordinates or nodes> This option must be given to a node path command. The <coordinates or nodes> should be a sequence of TikZ coordinates or node names, one directly after the other without commas (like with the plot coordinates path operation). Examples are (1,0) (2,2) or (a) (1,0) (b), where a and b are nodes."

Comment: yes it _said_ that but (unless I missed it) all examples use `(a) (b)` with names, I didn't feel confident in suggesting `fit={(0,0) (1,1)}` which hides the comma just on general syntax rules, as I didn't know what the code was supposed to do I have never used this library.  So as I said,  I commented on why it failed without offering a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use numerical coordinates, you must hide the `,` from the Ti*k*Z parser (and you should do the same if you use any of `[]=` in the coordinate specifications).

The `fit` library is normally used with symbolic coordinates or (more often) node names (in which case it uses the geographical coordinates of the node):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) coordinate(a) rectangle (1,1) coordinate(b);
   \node[draw=red, fit=(a) (b)] {};
   \node[draw=blue, dashed, fit={(0,0) (1,1)}, inner sep=1pt] {};
   \node[draw=green, fit={([xshift=0.5cm]a) (b)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from the snippet above]

Notice the `inner sep` effect.

Comment: Thank you. Why is there a space between the black and red squares, even though no `inner sep` option is specified for the red node?

Comment: Because `inner sep` default is not 0; it's something like 2 or 3 pt (Now I can't remember the exact value)